# Issue deploying Magento 2: Unable to get content

Tags: magento2, css, less, less-css

During deploy we get issues:

```
Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            0/2437              >-------------------frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2/2437              >--------------------------- 0%     1 sec
Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/print.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2437/2437           ============================ 100%   1 sec
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         879/3094            =======>-------------------- 28%    1 sec
Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles-old.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/print.less
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2437/2437           ============================ 100%   1 sec
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         3094/3094           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2449/2454           ===========================> 99%    1 sec
Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magentofrontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2437/2437           ============================ 100%   1 sec
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         3094/3094           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2454/2454           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/market/en_US                2390/2905           =======================>---- 82%    1 sec
Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib/web/mage/gfrontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2437/2437           ============================ 100%   1 sec
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         3094/3094           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2454/2454           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/market/en_US                2905/2905           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US         1769/2915           ================>----------- 60%    1 sec
Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/web/css/styles-m.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-inline.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/print.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/web/css/footer-mobile.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/web/css/footer-mobile_rtl.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/web/css/header-mobile_rtl.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2437/2437           ============================ 100%   1 sec
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         3094/3094           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2454/2454           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/market/en_US                2905/2905           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US         2915/2915           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US          168/2906            =>-------------------------- 5%     1 sec
Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2437/2437           ============================ 100%   1 sec
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         3094/3094           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2454/2454           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/market/en_US                2905/2905           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US         2915/2915           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US          2354/2906           ======================>----- 81%    2 secs
Compilation from source: /home/usr/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
Unable to get content for 'frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2437/2437           ============================ 100%   1 sec
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         3094/3094           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2454/2454           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/market/en_US                2905/2905           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/mobile_layout/en_US         2915/2915           ============================ 100%   1 sec
frontend/Sm/market_child/en_US          2906/2906           ============================ 100%   2 secs

Execution time: 16.570615768433
```

All frontend styles have crumbled. We tried to rebuild the entire css

```
rm -rf generated

rm -rf pub/static

rm -rf var/cache

rm -rf var/generation
```

etc. But still no result.  Any idea?

Comment: Check folder/file permissions

Comment: Also check the index.php is pointed towards pub/media path.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the `lib` folder is created properly (should be automatically created when composer installs `magento/magento2-base`) as that's where the `css/source/lib/_lib.less` file comes from.

You might be able to fix it by getting a new Magento 2 installation via Composer and copying the lib folder to your current installation.